# What exactly is mounting a file system?

Tags: filesystems, mount

What really happens when you 'mount a file system' ? At what level of the stack does it happen? Why is it even necessary?

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure which "stack" you're talking about, but let's give it a try:

I would say there are two mains things happening when you mount a filesystem:

First (and the most obvious) is the choice of the mounting point: if you regard the content of the filesystem to be mounted as a subtree of directories and files, you can specify where this subtree will be attached in the main tree by specifying the mounting point:

As an example, assume your new file system contains:

```
/dir1/file1
/dir1/file2
/dir3
/file3
```

And your current "tree" (made of other  file system(s)) looks like:

```
/usr
/home/usr1
/home/usr1/tmp
/home/usr2
/bin
```

If you mount your new filesystem at the mount point "/home/usr1/tmp", then you actually attach your new filesystem "subtree" at the mounting point, thus in the example creating the following tree:

```
/usr
/home/usr1
/home/usr1/tmp/dir1/file1
/home/usr1/tmp/dir1/file2
/home/usr1/tmp/dir3
/home/usr1/tmp/file3
/home/usr2
/bin
```

A more formal definition of the mount point can be found [here](http://www.linfo.org/mount_point.html).

Mount points are always needed when mounting a new filesystem, but "default mount points" can be found in /etc/fstab (assuming Linux), so sometimes it may look like some mount commands do not specify any mount point.

The second aspect of mounting a filesystem often implies defining its type and physical location.
The physical location can be a disk partition, or a remote server...
The type determines how the data found at this physical location are interpreted.

If you type:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /media
```

You are actually saying:

- Look at the physical location "cdrom"
- Interpret the 0s and 1s stored there as a iso9660 "structure", thus being able to see a file structure in the bunch of 0s and 1s that the "physical location" (device) contains
- Attach the subtree of directories and files found on the filesystem at mount point /media

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the Linux system as a tree. To add something to the tree hence making it accessible, the filesystem can be mounted, if that particular system is not needed anymore it can be removed from the tree, unmounted.
For more details check the mount command documentation:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/mount.htm